# How to change application colors with Flavors in Android

Tags: java, android, android-color, android-flavors

In my application, I have **2 flavors**, and I want to change the application's color (`res/color`) for each of this **flavors**!

Please see my code below at `build.gradle` file :

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    app1 {
        applicationId "com.app.myApp1"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App 1"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@drawable/logo_app1"
        ]
    }
    app2 {
        applicationId "com.app.myApp2"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App 2"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@drawable/logo_app2"
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't know on setting the `color.xml` for each of this **flavors**!

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you create a separate as below:

```
[Project Root]
  -[Module]
    -src
      -main
      -app1
        -res
          -drawable-*
            -logo_app.png
      -app2
        -res
          -drawable-*
            -logo_app.png
```

If you do it shold work on its own without needing to specify anything in the gradle file.

Article with no gradle file configuration: https://medium.com/@orafaaraujo/flavors-e01015eff979

Article with gradle file configuration: https://medium.com/@sgkantamani/android-product-flavors-eb526e35f9f1

Comment: In your method, not needed change in gradle.build file? android studio how can know set this colors?

Comment: You need to create a color folder in each of your flavor and puts the exact same name. For example in your 1rst flavor: `<color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>` and in your 2nd flavor : `<color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFF</color>`

Comment: Thanks, i tested it. i hope this way help me my friend

Comment: no worries, I edited my post with 2 articles that might help you.